# Resetting the photos live tile

Tags: windows-8, live-tiles

While working on an answer, I managed to get the photos live tile 'stuck' on a specific photo, which I don't even have on the disk at the moment. How would I reset the live tile to select random photos from my library again?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yeah, you did it [here](https://superuser.com/questions/490232/can-i-select-which-folders-the-photos-live-tile-chooses-from). If you ever want to go back to the default behavior, you can do this by changing the "Shuffle photos on app tile" option under Settings, which is in the charm at the right hand side.

It's a nice rule to remember that most of the times the settings at the bottom usually act upon the item in the application whereas the settings in the sidebar act upon the whole application.

Comment: Oh, I know when I did it. I just had no idea how to fix it. I make it a point to remember how exactly I got into trouble ;p. Will check and select as answer once this is tested on the win8 install.